# Rails: why am I having trouble accessing this member variable in a controller method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am seeing a very strange issue with a simple controller method. Either I am missing something fundamental or I am encountering a bug. My bet is on the former.

I have a `Thing` model with a `ThingController`.

A `Thing` has two variables, `name` and `display`, both strings.

`ThingController` (code below) has a method `toggle_display`, that toggles the contents of `display` between `"on"` and `"off"`.

The problem is that when I call this action, Rails finds the correct `Thing`, but `@thing.display` is nil. When I check the database, the value in the 'display' column is correct.

The strange part is that when I uncomment the third line in the code below (i.e. access `@thing.name` ***before*** accessing `@thing.display`) then `@thing.display` is fine - it isn't nil and it has the value I would expect. It's as if `@thing.display` only gets initialized correctly after I access `@thing.name`.

Any idea why I would see this very strange behavior?

```
def toggle_display
  @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])

  # @thing.name

  if @thing.display
    @thing.toggle_display_in_model
    @thing.save
  end

  redirect_to things_url
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that there's already a method named "display" in Kernel which conflicts with ActiveRecord's magic.

ActiveRecord defines the methods corresponding to the database fields in method_missing. So until method_missing is called, the methods don't actually exist. When you call name on @thing, method_missing is called because there is no name method. However when you call display (without previously calling another method that does not exist), method_missing is not called because display is already defined in Kernel and this definition is executed. And since Kernel's display method returns nil, you get nil.

Comment: Thanks very much - this is very clear and helps me enormously. I should have thought about the possibility of some sort of conflict. Is there a simple way that one can get an exhaustive list of the names one should avoid. Or is there a best practice that I should adopt to force a call to method_missing?

Comment: You can get a list of all methods that exist on ActiveRecord objects by typing `ActiveRecord::Base.instance_methods` into script/console.